# Put file connection to variable on SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, extract, 7zip

i want to do extract zip files on SSIS 2008, using execute process task. I've got confused because Arguments just can do 1 file process and 1 working directory. But i want to an Arguments and a working directory changes dynamic according to SQL table which is give the value for path on Arguments and Working directory. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to pass those values dynamically, then pass the values through varaibles

Comment: how to put them on variables?

Comment: Use a For loop container to pass sql values for path and woking directory. get the sql values and assing those values to the execute process task properties such as working directory etc using expressions. you can assign the sql query resultset to variables in the resultset tab.

Answer (score 0):

The operations provided by the File System task target individual file system objects. To
use it against multiple objects, you should use the Foreach Loop Container.
Just google for examples, you should find several